# What are all the new features of visual studio 2012 IDE?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Can some one list all the new features of vs 2012 IDE.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386063.aspx

Comment: Surely Microsoft did on their Visual Studio site?

Comment: These are the features of VS 2012 IDE if i understand the question right.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj618297.aspx

http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/03/01/more-power.aspx

Answer (score 2):

**Windows Metro style Apps**

- Designing and building Metro style apps
- Debugging, optimizing, and publishing Metro style apps

  **Visual Studio IDE**
- Projects and Solutions
- Window Management
- Search
- Code Editing for C++
- Code Editing for JavaScript

  **Languages**
- Visual Basic
- Visual C#
- Visual C++
- JavaScript
- Visual F#

  **Application Lifecycle Management and Team Foundation Server**
- Managing the application lifecycle
- Modeling applications
- Developing applications and collaborating more effectively as a team
- Automating and debugging builds
- Microsoft Test Manager

  **ASP.NET 4.5 and Web Development**
- ASP.NET 4.5 Core Services
- ASP.NET 4.5 Web Forms
- General Enhancements for Web Development
- Data-Related Enhancements for Web Development
- IIS Express for Web Development
- ASP.NET Web API

  **Other Enhancements**
- LightSwitch
- Data Application Development
- Graphics Tools
- Parallel Computing
- SharePoint Development
- Office Development
- .NET Framework 4.5

Comment: It is just copy from MSDN. I just wanted the new feature list of 2012 IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You can read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165079) document it's very interessant on msdn.